# Segmentation fault after compiled by nvcc

Tags: c++, c, cuda, segmentation-fault, nvcc

I tested the following simple code with NVIDIA's nvcc compiler. When I try to run the program,if the value of N is less than or equal to 512, it runs okay. But when I try to set N greater than 512 and run, it gives a segmentation fault. What's the reason for this?

```
#define N 1024 //changing value
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    float hA[N][N], hB[N][N], hC[N][N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            hA[i][j] = 1;
            hB[i][j] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack overflow? The arrays may be too big for your stack, so you might need dynamic allocation (have a look at `std::vector<float>`).

Comment: On a normal workstation, the amount of stack available to a process is usually in the single-digit megabyte range. You are using 12 megs of stack with those matrices.

Comment: you mean float *arr=new float[dim][dim](); or using the size as a local variable? Sorry, I'm not so proficient in C/C++

Comment: Your 3 arrays include 3145728 elements at all. That may be a stack overflow.

Comment: I mean `std::vector<float> hA(N*N);` etc. and then be clever with the indices. C/C++ is not a language. My suggestions are limited to C++.

Comment: If you really want to statically allocate 12MB of `float` data, move it out of `main` to file scope.

Comment: worth noting that nvcc isnt a compiler, your host platform compiler is compiling the code, and this problem has nothing to do with CUDA per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two ways you can allocate the matrices, the most common is to use a pointer-to-pointer-to-float, and then allocate first the outer dimension, and then allocate the inner dimension in a loop:

```
float** hA = new float*[N];
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    hA[i] = new float[N];
```

The second way is to have a pointer to an array, and allocate that:

```
float (*hA)[N] = new (float[N])[N];
```

---

But all that is moot since you might as well use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead:

```
std::vector<std::vector<float>> hA(N);
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    hA[i].push_back(std::vector<float>(N));
```

Comment: `array` of `array` would have the same problem. OP would need a `vector`.

Comment: A vector of vectors or an array of pointers is a very poor choice for storage which will be used in a GPU computing code. They are not portable. A simple flat NxN dynamic memory allocation is preferable.